# how to turn off GitHub generated (and broken) tarballs when I do a release?

Tags: github, release, autotools

I am an admin for the PIO project (https://github.com/NCAR/ParallelIO), a set of C/Fortran libraries which is built with autoconf/automake/libtool.

When I do a release, GitHub generates a tarball and a zip file of the repo. These are useless because they have not been generated by "make dist" which puts together the actual tarball.

I can add the actual tarball to the release page - is there any way to remove the broken ones that GitHub puts there? As it is, I just tell users not to use those, but that's not a great solution.

Another solution, used on some projects, is to commit the autotools-generated files to the release branch, so that GitHub releases are functional. That seems lame but might be the best option.

Comment: I do commit the autotools-generated files, for largely the same reason that Automake-generated makefiles package them in the distribution tarball: *building* the project for a supported platform should not require the Autotools to be installed on the build system.  This also somewhat addresses the fact that Autotools (especially Autoconf) inputs are more sensitive to the version of the Autotools to which they are fed than are most source files.

Comment: Not great, however you could [delete them afterwards](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/releases/#delete-a-release-asset).

Comment: Timothy Brown how do I delete them?